# Previous next record order statement

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL statement that should get me the previous or next record relative to the current record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM items
   WHERE category = ? AND $field $operator ? AND visible = 1
   ORDER BY $field $direction LIMIT 1
```

The variables are set like this:

```
// these two may change
$field   = 'name';
$getNext = true;

if($getNext){
  $direction = 'ASC';
  $operator  = '>';

}else{
  $direction = 'DESC';
  $operator  = '<';
}
```

This seems to work if `$field` is a unique field, but if it's not, I get some weird results when `$getNext` is set to false (previous record) :(

How can I fix this?

Comment: . . What are "weird results"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem that you are facing is that the sorting is not stable.  A stable sort always returns the same order of records every time it is run.  In SQL, you only get stable sorts when the values are unique.

You can fix this by adding `name` into the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM items
WHERE category = ? AND $field $operator ? AND visible = 1
ORDER BY $field $direction, name
LIMIT 1
```

When fields have the same value, the addition of `name` will make the sort stable and should get you the right results.

Comment: In the example above, name is already included in the sort ($field).

Comment: @asmecher . . . But then it should be unique because of the `distinct`.  What is the problem then?

Comment: Agreed, OTOH, but that approach will not allow next/previous browsing of entries that share the same name. Which might be the "weird results" he's talking about, though it's not clear.

Comment: yea this seems to work. now I have to add an interface for selecting multiple fields :x